# Safer alternative to MATLAB's `system` command

Tags: linux, matlab

I have been using MATLAB's `system` command to get the result of some linux commands, like in the following simple example:

```
[junk, result] = system('find ~/ -type f')
```

This works as expected, *unless* the user types into MATLAB's command window at the same time. Which during a long `find` command is not uncommon. If this happens then the user's input seems to get mixed up with the result of the `find` command (and then things break).

As an example, instead of:

```
/path/to/file/one
/path/to/file/two
/path/to/file/three
/path/to/file/four
```

I might get:

```
J/path/to/file/one
u/path/to/file/two
n/path/to/file/three
k/path/to/file/four
```

In order to demonstrate this easily, we can run something like:

```
[junk, result] = system('cat')
```

Type something into the command window and press CTRL+D to close the stream. The `result` variable will be whatever you typed in to the command window.

Is there a safer way for me to call system commands from MATLAB without risking corrupted input?

Comment: do you observe the same behavior when using `unix` instead of `system`?

Comment: The `system('cat')` example might be a bad reproduction case: `cat` is *supposed* to echo its stdin to stdout, and Matlab seems to hook its command window or console keyboard entry to stdin for system() calls. (Like shells do.) Lets you interact with programs needing user input. The `find` example is weirder; it's not supposed to randomly mix what it gets on stdin in to its output, and that looks like real cross-wiring. FWIW, I can reproduce both on OS X with R2014a.

Comment: @thewaywewalk - yes it has the same behaviour

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks goes to Andrew Janke for helping me find this solution.

To easily reproduce the error we can run the command:

```
[ret, out] = system('sleep 2');
```

If we type some characters while this is running, the `out` variable will be contaminated with what we typed.

The solution to this problem is to redirect stdin from /dev/null like the following:

```
[ret, out] = system('sleep 2 < /dev/null');
```

This stops the `out` variable from being contaminated by user input.

Interestingly though this seems to fix the original test-case for the current MATLAB session (tested on R2014a OSX and R2013b Linux) so if we do another `[ret, out] = system('sleep 2');` the output is no longer contaminated by user input.

Answer (score 4):

Wow. That behavior is surprising. Sounds worth reporting as a bug to MathWorks. I tested it on OS X, and see the same behavior.

As a workaround, you could re-implement `system()` using calls to the `java.lang.Process` and related objects in the JVM embedded in Matlab.

You'll need to:

- Use polling to keep Matlab's own input, especially Ctrl-C, live
- Use shell processing instead of passing the commands directly to ProcessBuilder to support expansion of `~` and other variables and wildcards, and to support specifying commands and their arguments in a single string like Matlab's system does.
  ** Alternately, you could expose the arguments-array form if you want lower-level control and don't want to deal with escaping and quoting strings for the shell. Both would be useful.
- Redirect the output to files, or periodically drain the child process's output buffers in your polling code.

Here's an example.

```
function [status,out,errout] = systemwithjava(cmd)
%SYSTEMCMD Version of system implemented with java.lang features
%
% [status,out,errout] = systemwithcmd(cmd)
%
% Written to work around issue with Matlab UI entry getting mixed up with 
% output captured by system().

if isunix
    % Use 'sh -s' to enable processing of single line command and expansion of ~
    % and other special characters, like the Matlab system() does
    pb = java.lang.ProcessBuilder({'bash', '-s'});
    % Redirect stdout to avoid filling up buffers
    myTempname = tempname;
    stdoutFile = [myTempname '.systemwithjava.out'];
    stderrFile = [myTempname '.systemwithjava.err'];
    pb.redirectOutput(java.io.File(stdoutFile));
    pb.redirectError(java.io.File(stderrFile));
    p = pb.start();
    RAII.cleanUpProcess = onCleanup(@() p.destroy());
    RAII.stdoutFile = onCleanup(@() delete(stdoutFile));
    RAII.stderrFile = onCleanup(@() delete(stderrFile));
    childStdin = java.io.PrintStream(p.getOutputStream());
    childStdin.println(cmd);
    childStdin.close();
else
    % TODO: Fill in Windows implementation here    
end

% Poll instead of waitFor() so Ctrl-C stays live
% This try/catch mechanism is lousy, but there is no isFinished() method.
% Could be done more cleanly with a Java worker that did waitFor() on a
% separate thread, and have the GUI event thread interrupt it on Ctrl-C.
status = [];
while true
    try
        status = p.exitValue();
        % If that returned, it means the process is finished
        break;
    catch err
        if isequal(err.identifier, 'MATLAB:Java:GenericException') ...
                && isa(err.ExceptionObject, 'java.lang.IllegalThreadStateException')
            % Means child process is still running
            % (Seriously, java.lang.Process, no "bool isFinished()"?
            % Just continue
        else
            rethrow(err);
        end
    end
    % Pause to allow UI event processing, including Ctrl-C
    pause(.01);
end

% Collect output
out = slurpfile(stdoutFile);
errout = slurpfile(stderrFile);
end

function out = slurpfile(file)
fid = fopen(file, 'r');
RAII.fid = onCleanup(@() fclose(fid));
out = fread(fid, 'char=>char')'; %'
end
```

I tried this out as best as I could, and it looks like it keeps the child process's output separate from keyboard input to the Matlab IDE. Keyboard input is buffered up and executed as additional commands after `systemwithjava()` returns. Ctrl-C stays live and will interrupt the function, letting the child process get killed.

Comment: Your comment "Redirect the output to files" gave me the idea to redirect STDIN. If I add ` < /dev/null` to the end of my find command then it seems to have fixed the problem. Do you get the same results? (I don't have a reliable way of reproducing the problem unless the disk/find is very slow)

Comment: Ah, good idea! I think it works. Here's a simpler repro: `[ret,out] = system('sleep 2')`. If I do that and mash the keys, I get junk in the output. But with `[ret,out] = system('sleep 2 < /dev/null')` I get a clean output even while mashing the keys.

Comment: Thanks for confirming Andrew. Feel free to add it to your answer and I'll mark as the accepted answer.

Comment: Andrew if you go back to `[ret,out] = system('sleep 2')` after using `< /dev/null` does it still have the same problem? For me it seems to fix itself so I can't recreate the problem.

Comment: Huh. Yep, same here: once I do a `< /dev/null` once, later plain `[ret,out] = system('sleep 2')` calls in the same session no longer pick up user keyboard input. (R2014a on OS X.) I have no idea what's happening here; smells like a bug.

Comment: Nope, this was your idea and it's a distinct mechanism: I think you should type this up as a separate answer, and self-accept it if you end up going with it. It can stand on its own.