# Use shell commands from Matlab

Tags: bash, matlab, ubuntu

I use a Matlab code and want to insert below Bash command between lines to select specific files.

```
du --max-depth 1 |
awk -v q='"' '$1 < 30000000 && $2 != "." {sub(/^[0-9\t ]+/, "", $0); print q $0 q}'
```

This command works well in the shell, but I am confused how I can use it between lines of Matlab code.

Comment: Use the `system` command

Comment: Did my answer solve your problem? If so, please consider marking it as accepted:)

Answer (score 6):

Under linux, `system` and `unix` do the same: they evaluate their string argument in the shell. For this you have to escape the single quotes due to MATLAB's string syntax, you do this by doubling each single quote:

```
[~,output]=system('du --max-depth 1 | awk -v q=''"'' ''$1 < 30000000 && $2 != "." {sub(/^[0-9\t ]+/, "", $0); print q $0 q}''');
```

This will save the output of your command to the string named `output`. The first output argument would be a status code. Although, depending on subsequent applications, you might want to drop the double quotes from your output altogether (i.e. omit the variable `q` and just `print $0` at the end).

Since your `output` is now a character vector, with newlines simply included as the `\n` character, you have to do some postprocessing to get meaningful file names. The simplest thing to do is to use `regexp` to split your string at the newlines, and then remembering to throw away the last (empty) string due to the final newline at the end of the string. If you heed my suggestion regarding the double quotes, here's what you do:

```
[~,output] = system('du --max-depth 1 | awk ''$1 < 30000000 && $2 != "." {sub(/^[0-9\t ]+/, "", $0); print $0}''');
filelist = regexp(output,'\n','split'); %split at newline
filelist = filelist(1:end-1); %throw away the last dubious part
```

Now `filelist` is a cell array with each element containing a string: the name of each object output by your script.

Be careful though: often input from the command window will garble the input to a `system` call, as if from STDIN. See [this important post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23948227/safer-alternative-to-matlabs-system-command). In principle you can fix some of this issue by redirecting STDIN of your system command to `/dev/null`, as in `du --max-depth 1 </dev/null | awk ...`, but I've found that not to be a general solution.

Answer (score 1):

Just to complete Andras Deak's answer the `bang` operator would also work:

```
!du --max-depth 1 |
awk -v q='"' '$1 < 30000000 && $2 != "." {sub(/^[0-9\t ]+/, "", $0); print q $0 q}'
```

Comment: The output of the command is a set of directories(/files?). You usually want to do something with that afterwards, for which you need the output of the command, which can only be caught with `system` and friends. Otherwise this would be preferable, as the `bang` might not have the input garbling problem of `system` (I wouldn't know, I always use `system` since my commands contain variables and I always need the output)